# Doing google app engine backend operation in java using spring

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm using spring and google app engine, backend operations (as I understood) requires a servlet to be defined in the web.xml file so how to do that with spring ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after lots of searching,I won't blame GAE for not putting plain english tutorials the guys there did magnificent job. I think I should have read the docs more carefully.

let's say you have a method(worker in GAE) that has the mapping of `http://localhost:8080/blabla/coolmethod` then if you need to excute it over a normal request just call the previous link but if you want to execute it over a backend operation you just add `http://nameofbackend.localhost:8080/blabla/coolmethod` and that's it!. so either it's a normal servlet or it's spring or what ever you just add that backend name as subdomain and hit that url.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, for spring-mvc applications, your `web.xml` should contain a servlet referencing your application context and a mapping of that servlet, e.g.:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/path-to-your/web-application-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This isn't the only method of configuration, check the Spring reference documentation for more details. Hope that helps.